# Functions of React Components

Tags: reactjs

I would like to understand the React code below; 
Specifically, I am assuming that the 
 
is rendering component of this but the "Welcome" in the snippet above refers to the "Welcome" function at the top and that the rendinring runs the function through 3 iterations, one for each name??

...

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Welcome name="Sara" />
      <Welcome name="Cahal" />
      <Welcome name="Edite" />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of **[Composing Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#composing-components)**.

> Components can refer to other components in their output.

This means that we can nest multiple components inside of a component. This is usually referred to as Parent/Child Components. A Parent Component can render many Child Components.

In the example you posted, they have created a **[functional stateless component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components)** called `<Welcome />`. The `<App />` component is the Parent Component and it needs to render the `<Welcome />` component three times, each with different data. They are using **[props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component)** to pass in a different name to each `<Welcome />` component.

When the `<App />` components render method is called, it will render the `<Welcome />` component three separate times, each with their own props.